# Optimize a design for current/charge oscillator

Tags: current-source, charge, multivibrator

I'm trying to understand how to design a circuit that cycles charges between two capacitors between cycles. Basically I want a large positive current pulse into one cap at the same time a large negative current pulse out of the other is happening, and then after a short delay to repeat in the opposite direction, back and forth on each cycle.

I decided to give it a try by tweaking an astable multivibrator as starting point. I analysed the one from falstad but I noticed that the current draw to the capacitors is far from time-symmetric.

I tweaked the circuit substantially in order to achieve better shaped current peaks

[circuit](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAOaAmZYCcB2BzkcBmLUhJBSECqhAUwFowwAoAd3DDRABZkQ0kfnyjsBQ3vwzD%20kMdMkgiyHorkAnTtxHNuYHADYoSjeJlnwh41jgtNCkQv1GqN08tUiPllyZYBjLR8LZ2MYeEgEUmiY2KwkGDxMeJ4iNJwcLkgIcOyApRVgpysqXMQ4irJeaCI4GwxInjBItBwoWDyAFwECAQQjbzR%204wgGBGgDAwR9LD5DIfxVBhgp2p4EHB40AxxIXd7mqgATOgAzAEMAVwAbTvkJUIUhl3kDq0EpYbluj76jXT%20I3aBkgIMwaD4yCIOCwRAMRHamS4tVhKVSPAy4DgIBOFxudwASkERAZPLJjDxaGF2ggWABzIKtPRcEyqUr0gqqJmc1lhFgAD3AUQELJmIqQqjARgAwqxBUR9CKEekRUZJTK0AKUEhtlRmkZtgj1SAAIpypQ2PpYXjMAQGbTgIwmzWUhHYbi-NAQgSUkZgAD6z39kH9TUgaH9CGD0ADTED-uY-qILFdAhwHokax9pSxgf6wdDzQjUZgPH9cYjzSTKcgysE4AwSgQehBxmQCYwBbDxejZYr-vbydTYB4ksboSlOZwHfbIe7kejsYDEenyZ%20wyzk95euBoKEXEh0Nh8MRuhRJAQo6IGLahxxZyutzEAIhepZXrZz9FVi3H9EHF-b1f16OQOGeXliheBktyIesYObPkfl9WCqDSAZ6x3MYJimGY5ntchCmWCYEDWDYth2PYhH4O9cUfO4GTQpQ4SYgYDHJUDsyUetflCDjGKzRi-z4wo-0GX1hMlKwmn%20Ud-yCUJkD1WS5ECRTwFkv8RzZdoIkgJYVj3cF9GIKUDDABFclYQJuS0m0ZO0so4CWcZJnIdM8CiPB3R0vJ7CAjS3l8Vh7Aed503U7TWAA79-nfb0JIEb1vF4sRBKSwoUoAewbEBSVy3hIFIFBoBUQqSK4QQeCwQhZA6bJjG4a0DBYbK2jyqhUhI6h2j0AQQDaZNsv4dreCILqEnQcA%20v4QalDa7TOoRCaIA9OalBagpcoWsalvaFa%20uUdbsvMraKUK60JtUBE9GVFggA)

Notice how sharp the current pulse look in the scope, this is precisely what I'm after shape-wise, specially the fact that the pulses alternate between sources and sinks. The goal is of course improve the peak current relative to the total circuit power draw. Probably a different type of circuit will be better suited, which is something I'm very interested in learning about.

Consider that I'm learning and it is entirely possible that this tweak is the wrong thing to do to achieve what I'm after, I am glad to receive your help or suggestion on my design task

Comment: At 12V be careful about reverse BE breakdown of Q1 and Q2. It will discharge the cap almost immediately to about 6V.

Comment: Also the BE of added transistors never allow to rise a voltage on Q1,Q2 collectors. The BE will clamp this voltage. So the C1 and C2 cannot be charged.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Andyaka possible ways to make the caps current draw become more pulse-like and/or symmetric

Comment: You need to do better than that to help yourself. Of course it might be possible but, how bad is it currently, what capacitors are you talking about and, how much better do you want things to be? Also, you should redraw your circuit so that it looks like you care about getting an answer.

Comment: I've updated the question, also updated the circuit, pointing to a falstad simulation url, and also narrowed down the scope of the question a little bit, hope that is enough to be deserving of help